# Initilizing 2d array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

Im geting a null pointer exeception, I thought i had initilized all the objects in the array but it seems i have gone wrong some where.

Heres the code for this class. It works fine when using a MapBlock object outside of a array.

The execption is when it trys to access the object in the update method.

```
public class Game { 
    private Scanner scan;

    // map stuff
    MapBlock[][] mapObjects;


    // List of Textures
    Texture path;
    Texture tower;
    Texture grass;

    Game(){ 
        // Textures
        path = loadTexture("path");
        tower = loadTexture("tower");
        grass = loadTexture("grass");



        mapObjects = new MapBlock[24][16];

        loadLevelFile("level1");        

    }

    public void update(){
        if(mapObjects[0][0] == null)
            System.out.println("its null!!!");
        mapObjects[0][0].update();
    }

    public void render(){
        mapObjects[0][0].render();      
    }




    private Texture loadTexture(String imageName){
        try {
            return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/" + imageName + ".png")));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException r){
            r.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void loadLevelFile(String mapName){
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("res/" + mapName + ".txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not open "+ mapName +" file!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String obj;
        int i = 0, t = 0;

        while(scan.hasNext()){
            obj = scan.next();

            if(obj == "o"){
                mapObjects[i][t] = new MapBlock("GRASS", t*32, i*32, grass);

            }else if(obj == "x"){
                mapObjects[i][t] = new MapBlock("PATH", t*32, i*32, path);

            }else if(obj == "i"){
                mapObjects[i][t] = new MapBlock("TOWER", t*32, i*32, tower);                    
            }

            if(i < 24){
                i++;
            }else{
                i = 0;
                t ++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Post the full exception message.

Comment: where are you getting this exception

Comment: its null!!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Game.update(Game.java:41)
 at Main.update(Main.java:65)
 at Main.gameLoop(Main.java:59)
 at Main.main(Main.java:22).            Its on the same line it trys to run mapObjects[0][0].update(); sorry its all massed together cant hit enter without posting

Comment: is it possible it's never going into your loop? perhaps scan never has next?

Comment: step through your code that reads from the file... it seems that the file is not being loaded the way you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `loadLevelFile` method:

```
-> if(obj == "o"){
// ...
-> }else if(obj == "x"){
// ...  
-> }else if(obj == "i"){
// ...
}
```

You're comparing strings with `==` and not `.equals()`, likely this causes the instantiation of your `mapObjects` array to not happen.

Try changing it to:

```
if(obj.equals("o")){
// ...
}else if(obj.equals("x")){
// ...  
}else if(obj.equals("i")){
// ...
}
```

The error occurs here:

```
if(mapObjects[0][0] == null)
    System.out.println("its null!!!");
mapObjects[0][0].update(); <- Error happens here
```

because the object at `mapObjects[0][0]` is still `null`, as the `loadLevelFile` method did not instantiate it.

Comment: Thank you, Strings my weak point! It hadnt occured to me the if()'s could be part of the problem. It works now thank you, also i had to changce if(i < 24)  to if(i < 23) to stop a out of bounds error and i just worked out why while typing this lol. Thanks again!

Comment: @richilonsdale Just a suggestion in the future; add the final `else` in any daisy-chain style `if-else if- else if-` clauses, and if you aren't expecting to ever get there throw/print an error; `else { System.out.println("This should not have happened."); }`. That way you would have been alerted to this issue much quicker and at its actual source.

Comment: Thats a great suggestion, thank you very much for your help, iv learnt more from the people on this site today then the last couple weeks reading books and watching youtube for info.